# custom MSBuild task fails to complete

Tags: android, gradle, msbuild, adb, msbuild-task

We are calling a python script which then processes our source code and calls android ndkbuild.

It appears as though the first build after a restart (I haven't been able to reproduce it any other time than the first build after a restart) our main task fails to complete.  This is locking up the build process and the only way to cancel it is manually end the MSBuild processes from task manager.

I believe what we are doing is very basic and straight forward:

MsBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\Google:

```
 <Target Name="Build">
   <ItemGroup Condition="$(UseVerbose)=='true'">
     <v Include="--verbose"/>
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup Condition="$(ConfigurationType)=='Application'">
     <g  Condition="$(UseGradle)=='true'" Include="--gradle"/>
     <p Include="-p $(PathOrProject)"/>
     <cores Include="--cores 10"/>
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup Condition="$(ConfigurationType)!='Application'">
     <p Include="--path $(PathOrProject)"/>
     <cores Include="--cores 1"/>
   </ItemGroup>
   <Exec Command="echo Build Task started"/>
   <Exec Command="cmd /C python $(WORK_TOOLS_DIR)\bin\PythonScripts\buildAndroid.py @(p) -c $(Configuration)_$(Platform) --ndk_path $(NDKPath) @(cores) @(g) @(v)" />
   <Exec Command="echo Build Task is Done"/>
 </Target>
```

Last lines of BuildAndroid.py

`print('Exiting successful Error 0')
sys.exit(0)`

Output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: GameCore, Configuration: Debug Google ------
2>------ Build started: Project: Geometry, Configuration: Debug Google ------
3>------ Build started: Project: Graphics, Configuration: Debug Google ------
4>------ Build started: Project: Network, Configuration: Debug Google ------
5>------ Build started: Project: CDPhysics, Configuration: Debug Google ------
6>------ Skipped Build: Project: PCCore, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
6>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
7>------ Build started: Project: UI3d, Configuration: Debug Google ------
8>------ Skipped Build: Project: RendererDX11, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
8>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
9>------ Build started: Project: SoundWWise, Configuration: Debug Google ------
10>------ Build started: Project: Android_Platform, Configuration: Debug Google ------
2>  Build Task started
1>  Build Task started
4>  Build Task started
3>  Build Task started
10>  Build Task started
5>  Build Task started
7>  Build Task started
9>  Build Task started
5>  Exiting successful Error 0
1>  Exiting successful Error 0
4>  Exiting successful Error 0
9>  Exiting successful Error 0
5>  Build Task is Done
2>  Exiting successful Error 0
1>  Build Task is Done
9>  Build Task is Done
4>  Build Task is Done
2>  Build Task is Done
7>  Exiting successful Error 0
7>  Build Task is Done
10>  Exiting successful Error 0
10>  Build Task is Done
3>  Exiting successful Error 0
3>  Build Task is Done
11>------ Build started: Project: MainProject, Configuration: Debug Google ------
11>  Build Task started
... (output for BuildAroid.py)
11>  Exiting successful Error 0
```

At this point the build hangs and just sits there, never to return.

When the MSBuild process is killed and select build (and any other calls of build except for just after a restart) we get the same output except at the end where it finishes successfully with the following output:

```
11>  Exiting successful Error 0
11>  Build Task is Done
========== Build: 9 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 2 skipped ==========
```

I have tried to set a user environment variable MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE to 1 also the calling "cmd /c python ..." was an attempt to solve this.  I have also disabled all of the options under the Tools->Options->Python Tools->Deubugging menu

When the command line is run outside of Visual Studio (from the command prompt) there are no issues.

We are using Python 3.3.5

This appears to have something to do with Gradle and how we are calling it.  Exact same script without gradle enabled and there is no problem.

Comment: Does the project use any common props/targets? if so, it does overwrite the `Build` target and I'm wondering if that is done intentionally..
Also, can the exec command be called concurrently or does it lock files? I don't know if design time builds (that aren't supposed to create build outputs but call the `Build` target) have concurrency checks.

Comment: Just to make sure the command really returns: if you add <Message Text="Finished"/> after the Exec task, does it print that?

Comment: I revised the description of the issue with more information and clarification.  

The only targets we are overwriting are Build, Compile and Clean.

Comment: Solution:   Turns out the build script kicks off 2 services, adb and one for Gradle.  MSBuild is waiting for those services to end before MSBuild will complete.  

We do a prebuild step of powershell start-process adb start-server and start gradle with the no daemon option (which just kills the process once gradle finishes).